# What's this printing technique called?

Tags: print-design, 3d, style-identification

Basically printing 3d letters for indoors (or outdoor) like on the picture? Is there a special printing technique involved in the making of these letters?

[image]
[image]

Comment: It's not "printing". It's manufacturing, like any furniture or object. Just because the shapes happen to be letters it doesn't change the general process. They could easily be window trim, or fenceposts, or light finials. They are cut, shaped, sanded, welded, or poured, and painted like anything else.

Comment: I see! Thanks for the answer. I was searching for companies, shops that do this, but i failed to find one. Hence the reason for me being here.

Comment: You'll need to find woodworkers, metalworkers, or machinists. Few design company will do this outright, they *might* manage it for you, for a fee, and subcontract the work out to a manufacturer.

Comment: This is where the difference of design an engineering goes. You might use a 3d printer tough. but you would need to do the STL mesh yourself.

Comment: Sign shops also do this sort of work all the time.

Comment: @Scott: I do agree, but some methods, e.g. laser or waterjet cutting, do have similarities with plotting/printing.

Comment: Similarities, yes. But often not part of a "designer's" print capabilities.

Comment: A surprisingly large number of designers will have a Roland desktop CNC router or mill about the place for precisely this sort of thing (on a small scale, at least), as will any number of "engraving" kiosks is large malls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no printing technique for this but these are custom made letters.  Based on the pictures I would assume the top are metal letters possibly formed and painted at a lighted sign shop.  The bottom letters, based on the texture in the light, appear to be foam letters.  There are many variations to 3D letters.  A simple google search for the following could help you narrow down the type of letters you may need:

- Injection molded
- Formed Plastic
- Cast Metal
- Cut Metal
- Cut Plastic
- Metal Laminate
- Fabricated Metal